# three-dimensional plot of the vector field with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file representing a vector field and would like to make a three dimensional plot with gnuplot.

The data set is something like this:

```
0.001    -0.002   0.004
0.003     0.007   -0.005
```

and so on

where the columns represent the Cartesian components of the vector.

How can I make the plot?

Comment: What does your data mean?

Answer (score 2):

The plotting style `vectors` is for drawing vector fields. But that requires six values in 3D, with the meaning of `x  y  z  xdelta  ydelta  zdelta`. Then you can draw with

```
splot 'file.txt' with vectors
```

To test with your data (don't know their meaning), you could plot the vectors along a line

```
splot 'file.txt' using ($0*0.01):(0):(0):1:2:3
```

Comment: If you got the data file with six columns, you need `using 1:2:3:4:5:6`

Comment: @Bernhard Right, my using statement was left from testing with the user's three column data. I updated the answer, thanks.